# Methods operator overloading

Tags: python, overloading, operator-keyword

How Python chooses which object to use the method overload?

For example:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.data = other
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.data + other
    def __radd__(self,other):
        return self.data + other
X = a(1) 
X+1
1+X
```

Why in `X + 1` expression , calls a method `__add__` in object at the left, and in expression `1 + X` method `__add__` is called at object on the right?

Comment: Did you mean `__radd__` in the `1+X` case?  Because you wrote `__add__`.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)?

Comment: Mr. user2494676 Please check you question, we believe you have typo read @SethMMorton's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X+1
```

first, calls:

```
X.__add__(1)
```

That succeeds, so no further work is needed.

---

On the other hand, this:

```
1+X
```

calls

```
(1).__add__(X)
```

That fails because `int` doesn't know how to interface with a class `a`. "As a last resort" this is tried instead:

```
X.__radd__(1)
```

From the [docs on `__radd__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__):

> These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types.

Comment: FYI, `print (1).__add__(10)` will print `11`.

Comment: ah yes the parentheses! that helps avoid going off on my tangent

Comment: @thefourtheye may I ask why there must be the `()`? why it's not like `''.join(['a', 'b'])`?

Comment: @zhangxaochen Otherwise the parser thinks that `1.` is the beginning of a floating point number, but `_` is not valid in floats. Thats why we have to explicitly make Python evaluate `1` separately.

Comment: @thefourtheye oh I didn't notice that. But since digits can't be the start of a method name, why the parser couldn't tell floats and method calls apart?

Comment: @zhangxaochen It is because of the `.`. The moment it sees a dot, it expects the next character to be a valid number or an arithmetic operator or nothing. :)

Comment: @thefourtheye yes I know it does so at the moment, just curious if it would expect a method call in the future, since there will be no ambiguity I think.